# Use abstract class as field in mongodb with Spring Data Java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, abstract-class

I'm trying to use an abstract class as field of a MongoDB document, using Spring Data. Here's an example (I'm using lombok for getter/setter):

```
@Data
@Document
public class User {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private List<Vehicle> vehicles;
}

@Data
public abstract class Vehicle {
   private String type; 
}

@Data
public class Car extends Vehicle {
   private int seats;
   private String fuel;
}

@Data
public class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
   private int cc;
}
```

Clearly, this code does not work because it cannot instantiate the Vehicle class when I read data from the DB. Now my question is: how can automatically instantiate the correct subclass basing on the type field of the abstarct class?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I tried using the following method to solve, but it seems not work:

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Car.class, name = "CAR"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Motorcycle.class, name = "MOTORCYCLE")
})
public abstract class Vehicle {
   private String type; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of the following will work:

1. Remove JsonSubTypes and JsonTypeInfo annotations
2. Check if your classes inheriting from "Vehicle" do not contain @TypeAlias("Car/Moto") annotation - the value given there overrides the "_class" field in the default MongoTemplate configuration.
3. Download the problematic record from the MongoDb database and make sure that the "_class" field contains the correct (full) classpath for Car/Motorcycle classes.
4. You can try the collection name in the @Document annotation
5. Update drivers and libraries related to Mongo.